# image:hover with opacity not staying behind my fixed header?

Tags: css, hover, css-position, z-index, opacity

I am having trouble trying to work something out. I have added some opacity to my "image:hover", however with this activated it seems to override my fixed header. I have tried putting the header on a "z-index: 0;" and the image on a "z-index; -1" but still no luck.

(Please note, this is very much still a work in progress...)

Thanks in advance

[Here is a screenshot to show what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5EUx.jpg)

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgb(247, 40, 40);
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.nav-link,
.project-title,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

#welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
h1 {
  padding-top: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sub-title {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#proj-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.proj-img {
  max-height: 20em;
  margin: 0 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.proj-img:hover {
  opacity: 60%;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=
    , initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <title>Maria Castro | Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Work</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="welcome-section">
      <h1>Hi, I'm Maria Castro.</h1>
      <p class="sub-title">Junior Front End Developer</p>
    </section>
    <section id="projects">
      <h2 class="project-title">My work</h2>
      <div id="proj-flex">
        <div id="project-1" href="#">
          <a href="https://ki05u.csb.app/" target="_blank">
            <img class="proj-img" src="images/weatherapp1.jpg" />
          </a>
          <p>Weather Widget</p>
        </div>
        <div id="project-2">
          <a
            href="https://codepen.io/mariaalouisaa/full/rNyLjYa"
            target="_blank"
            ><img class="proj-img" src="images/techdoc.jpg" />
          </a>
          <p>Technical Doc</p>
        </div>
        <div id="project-3" href="#">
          <a href="https://rzgbb.csb.app/" target="_blank"
            ><img class="proj-img" src="images/weatherapp2.jpg"
          /></a>
          <p>Weather App</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="connect">
      <a class="connect-link" id="profile-link" href="#">LinkedIn</a>
      <a class="connect-link" href="#">FCC</a>
      <a class="connect-link" href="#">Codepen</a>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your example, even by adding a proper image, but I can't recreate your problem. If could adding a screenshot of the issue would really help. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Vijay, thanks for having a look. I have added a screenshot of the problem. Please note, that if the image:hover is not active, images remain behind the fixed header.

Comment: Amazing, that did the job - thanks so much Vijay. Also, that's great to know, I shall keep my z-index values positive from now on. Thanks again, Maria

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as correct so in future anyone can check what caused the issue? Thanks :)

Comment: Done  Thanks again for the solution!

Comment: @mariaalouisaa How did you resolved this issue? in my case I am also facing same but the difference is I have table with fixed header, one of the column has icon on icon hover we show tooltip and it getting hidden behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the screenshot, it helped me to recreate the issue at my local. I solved the issue by removing the `z-index` values on `header` and `.proj-img`:

```
header { 
  /* remove z-index */
  /* z-index: 0; */
}
.proj-img { 
  /* remove z-index */
  /* z-index: -1; */
}
```

I still don't know how removing these z-index helps solve the problem, but generally speaking using values less than one is not ideal. Just to make sure that the header is always on top of everything else, you can do something like this:

```
// HTML
<header class="header" />
<div class="container">
  // rest of the content inside this div

// CSS
.header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Since the index value of `.container` parent is lower than `.header`, any element inside the container, even if they have `z-index` higher than three (3); `.header` will be always above.